# Jasmine error in visual studio. "undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'expect(player).toBePlaying(song)')"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, jasmine

I have installed "Jasmine Test Framework" package in visual studio 2013.

When I ran the default tests for jasmine-included file PlayerSpec.js in the "Test Explorer" window all tests fail with this error:

> "Can't find variable: Player"

So I added these references to the beginning of PlayerSpec.js:

```
/// <reference path="Player.js" /> 
/// <reference path="Song.js" />
```

Now the error is fixed but I am getting this error:

> undefined is not a constructor (evaluating
>   'expect(player).toBePlaying(song)')

I tried adding a reference to jasmine.js but that didn't fix it.
What reference do I need to add and to where?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add a reference to the SpecHelper.js file. So at the start of PlayerSpec.js I added this:

```
/// <reference path="Player.js" />
/// <reference path="Song.js" />
/// <reference path="SpecHelper.js" />
```